# what is the difference between DX,SX,LX

Tags: cpu-architecture

I am confused with followings

- DX-for desktop
- SX-high performance and cheap
- SL-for laptops

Are they CPU brands?and how they affect to the performance of the computer?

Thanks in advance
:)

Comment: How did you learn about this? Sounds like 1990s era Intel CPUs.

Comment: I have removed the old question and post a new.

Comment: If you want to ask a new question, then do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, these denominations existed for both i386 and i486 processors:

`i386-DX` : full featured 32 bits external bus, 32 bits internal bus i386.

`i386-SX` : 16 bits external bus, 32 bits internal bus i386.

`i386-SL` : i386-SX made for latops.

`i486-DX` : full featured i486, with internal numeric processor.

`i486-SX` : i486 but with disabled numeric processor.

`i486-SL` : i486 (don't remember if with or without numeric processor) for laptops.